# URL Rewriter.NET and multiple querystrings

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url-rewriting

I'm stressing out trying to create a url rewriter.net rule for my web site.

I have a link

```
 http://localhost/Pages/CategoryList.aspx?ID=2&Page=1
```

And I want replace it by this

```
 http://localhost/Category/2.aspx?Page=1
```

I tried the following:

```
<rewrite url="~/Category/(.+).aspx?Page=(.+)" to="~/Pages/CategoryList.aspx?ID=$1&amp;Page=$2" />
```

But it didn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why would you want to keep the .aspx? You could make a prettier (and more semantic) url fairly easily with rewriting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
<rewrite url="~/Category/(.+).aspx(\?(.*))?" to="~/Pages/CategoryList.aspx?ID=$1&amp;$3" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<rewrite url="~/Category/([0-9]+)\.aspx\?Page=([0-9]+)" to="~/Pages/CategoryList.aspx?ID=$1&amp;Page=$2" />
```

Or better(shorter):

```
<rewrite url="~/Category/(d+)\.aspx\?Page=(d+)" to="~/Pages/CategoryList.aspx?ID=$1&amp;Page=$2" />
```

I'm thinking that the "." you're using is too greedy and matches too much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add:

```
<httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
</httpModules>
```

to your `web.config` file?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to escape some special symbols ('.' and '?'), and not sure about the '~':

```
<rewrite url=".*/Category/(.+)\.aspx\?Page=(.+)" to="/Pages/CategoryList.aspx?ID=$1&amp;Page=$2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<rewrite url="~/Category/(.+)\.aspx\?Page=(.+)" 
         to ="~/Pages/CategoryList.aspx?ID=$1&amp;Page=$2" />
```